# Samba in Ubuntu 18.04 cannot be restarted during upgrade process

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with a (for me) working samba configuration (until today).

With the execution from the command "sudo apt upgrade" some php7.2 and php7.4-modules updates were executed. 
Perhaps a samba upgrade was made also. This i don't know exactly. But now i gets suddenly this message during the upgrade (and the upgrade is aborted then):

```
Jan 24 14:04:07 Kolibri systemd[1]: Starting Samba NMB Daemon...
Jan 24 14:04:07 Kolibri nmbd[13945]: [2020/01/24 14:04:07.354440, 0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:135(daemon_status)
Jan 24 14:04:07 Kolibri nmbd[13945]: STATUS=daemon 'nmbd' : No local IPv4 non-loopback interfaces available, waiting for interface ...NOTE: NetBIOS name resolution is not supported for Internet Protocol Version 6 (IPv6).
Jan 24 14:05:37 Kolibri systemd[1]: nmbd.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jan 24 14:05:37 Kolibri systemd[1]: nmbd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jan 24 14:05:37 Kolibri systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba NMB Daemon.
```

To make my samba configuration working i used this installation guide: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-configure-samba-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Notices:

- The command `sudo systemctl restart nmbd` didn't work neither during the samba configuration nor now. I get the error message "Failed to start nbmd.service: Unit nbmd.service not found" when i call the command now.
- I only installed "users" from samba installation guide (not josh)
- In smb.conf i set the interfaces-line to `bind interfaces only = no`
- I use a wlan antenna to get access to Internet. I don't use a LAN cable. i don't know if this is important as info for you.

Can you help me please why samba cannot be restarted? I made some internet research but didn't find a solution.

Thanxs in advance.

**Update**

I solved a little bit from my problem. i set the correct interfaces in line `interfaces = ...` in smb.conf and now i can start nbmd-service.

But now i'm getting the next error message (which i'm not understanding until now) during the upgrade process:

```
samba (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15) wird eingerichtet ...
Samba is not being run as an AD Domain Controller.
Please ignore the following error about deb-systemd-helper not finding samba-ad-dc.service.
Failed to preset unit: Unit file /etc/systemd/system/samba-ad-dc.service is masked.
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: systemctl preset failed on samba-ad-dc.service: No such file or directory
Trigger für libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) werden verarbeitet ...
W: APT had planned for dpkg to do more than it reported back (0 vs 4).
   Affected packages: samba:amd64
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the first little problem i could make `sudo apt autoremove` and `sudo apt autoclean` and now the whole upgrade process is now working again. Problem is fixed.